# Training Convolutional Neural Network too slowly

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf and edited some of the code for my own usage. However, every epoch is training too slow (2 mins per epoch) whereas, without editing, it takes less than 1 second per epode. I have a numpy array x_train of shape (209, 20000) and numpy array y_train of shape (209, 2). Could it be that my numpy array is too big?

The function train_step is the one that is taking too much time. The line being:
        _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
            [train_op, global_step, train_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
            feed_dict)

Edit: To clarify, what I changed from the code is using my own preprocessed data instead of data_helpers.py. I read in strings of size 20000 from 2 text files and put them into a list of length 209. Then, I load the data in train.py and change the list into a numpy array, and reshaping it after:

```
x = np.array(x_text)
x = np.reshape(x, (209, 20000))
```

The rest of the code should be the same.

```
    def train_step(x_batch, y_batch):
        """
        A single training step
        """
        feed_dict = {
          cnn.input_x: x_batch,
          cnn.input_y: y_batch,
          cnn.dropout_keep_prob: FLAGS.dropout_keep_prob
        }
        '''The slow part is the line below'''
        _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
            [train_op, global_step, train_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
            feed_dict)
        time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        print("{}: step {}, loss {:g}, acc {:g}".format(time_str, step, loss, accuracy))
        train_summary_writer.add_summary(summaries, step)

    # Generate batches
    batches = data_helpers.batch_iter(
        list(zip(x_train, y_train)), FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)
    # Training loop. For each batch...
    for batch in batches:
        x_batch, y_batch = zip(*batch)
        train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
        current_step = tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step)
        if current_step % FLAGS.evaluate_every == 0:
            print("\nEvaluation:")
            dev_step(x_dev, y_dev, writer=dev_summary_writer)
            print("")
        if current_step % FLAGS.checkpoint_every == 0:
            path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=current_step)
            print("Saved model checkpoint to {}\n".format(path))
```

Comment: The bigger your batches the longer it will take for one epoch to finish. Same with the size of your x and y arrays. But to get to your actual question, how is somebody supposed to answer what makes your code slow if you don't tell us what you have changed from the original?

Comment: Edited. Please let me know if there is anything else unclear. Thank you.